What does "como cuando" mean?
There is the context that translates well into English.

Me divertí como cuando tenía 5 años. - I had fun like when I was 5 years old

And then there are those that seem weird or incomplete when thinking of it as "like when" and that a simple cuando is all that is needed?
Is this use of como cuando coloquial and what does it mean exactly?

Como cuando llega la hora del recreo en el GYM.



Como cuando te pareces a tu peluche favorito de la infancia.



Como cuando ni siquiera tú entiendes tu propio idioma


I'm from Spain and I agree with  you that in those memes, "como" is not necessary. There is no comparison or equivalence between two situations, one in the present and another in the past. Only ONE situation is depicted explicitly. For me it's more natural to use just "cuando".

I’m voting to close this question because translation into English is not a part of this site.

Soy nativo colombiano, te puedo decir que estos son conocidos como "memes" una imagen con un texto generalmente para hacer chistes, el "como cuando" se usa para comparar, en la primera imagen por ejemplo compara una situación con otra y es que el "recreo" se conoce como esa hora en el colegio donde te comes lo que llevas en la lonchera y sales a jugar, y el hecho de comer sandwich en el gimnasio no es común y que lo comparen con el recreo es muy gracioso, o sea, eso lo hacíamos de niños; la otra imagen también compara en este caso un mono –o mico– con una "mona" como se le conoce popularmente en Colombia a las mujeres rubias (no sé si en otros países latinos les dicen igual). Entonces, en resumen es un inicio de una frase para hacer una comparación que es usada popularmente en los memes o a veces en comentarios para hacer chistes.
Espero haber sido claro.

Quizás es algo dialectal, es decir propio del español que se habla en Colombia. A mí me "suena" mejor sin el "como". Si lo quitas se entiende igual, ¿no?

Correcto es una forma popular de hacer ese tipo de chistes en memes aunque en comentarios se pueden hacer también, hasta donde sé solo en Colombia.
